Fast Startup (Hibernate): Windows failed fast startup with error status 0xC00000D4
The windows Fast Startup feature has a problem in my HP Victus 15 laptop.
i have it enabled from control panel, if i shutdown the laptop and leave it for like a day, when i turn it on, it is doing a cold boot not fast startup.
i can know from windows task manager when i look at the CPU Uptime i see it starts from 00:00:01 that is a cold boot, in a normal condition, if fast startup feature is working, it should continue incrementing the CPU Uptime from the previous state.
and in the Windows Event Viewer i get Two Error events.
First Error Event:
Source: Kernel-Boot
Event ID (158)
Task Category (53)

Error: BL_LOG_ERROR_RES_HW_CHANGE: Hardware or firmware settings have changes since hibernate. Status: {Incorrect Volume}
The target file of a rename request is located on a different device than the source of the rename request.


Second Error Event:
Source: Kernel-Boot
Event ID (29)
Task Category (None)

Windows failed fast startup with error status 0xC00000D4.


when i generate a Sleep Study Report, i do see Abnormal Shutdown :

i tried windows 10 same issue, windows 11 same issue.
i also did run a compontents test using HP PC Hardware Diagnostics from BIOS and all the tests passed no issues found, all components work as expected.

i have all the drivers and windows updates up-to-date.

i also tried disabling all programs from the Startup apps and the issue persists.

disabled all non-microsoft services, and issue persists.

the battery works as expected, no problem with it.


I need Fast Startup to be enabled in my laptop, so i don't want to disable it.
Anyone have a clue what is causing this issue to happen? i have this issue for months with no luck figuring it out!

@Ramhound it is plugged into power only when i use it, when i turn it off i disconnect the power source.

@Ramhound the behavior i'm describing happens when i leave the machine unplugged, as i said i turn it off and disconnect the charger, so it becomes on battery, secondly, i don't think battery gets drained all the way down because when i turn it back on later the battery is at where i left it, also, the problem happened in a short period after turn off like in 5min it also happened, so don't think battery drain is the causer.

@Ramhound that didn't help, same errors.

If the computer is in Sleep, it continuously uses power, until, when on battery, it must shut down. True Hibernation serializes the current state to storage, and then shuts down completely.
However, there are now various ersatz replacements for true Hibernation, a plethora of power states. Currently, in the so-called S4 Hibernate state, "The system appears to be off. Power consumption is reduced [but still being used ed.]. Some components remain powered so the computer can wake from input from the keyboard, LAN, or a USB device."
Only in the G3 state is the PC mechanically off and consuming no power (other than battery cell-balancing, and perhaps certain security chips). You can try turning off Fast Boot, and the laptop might enter G3 when hibernated... or not.
You can check which Sleep states are supported on your machine. You can also change the Power Options to allow graceful hibernation after Sleep drains the battery, and turn off any wake on... setting, such as on LAN, mouse or keyboard, which continue to drain the battery.

On the plan in effect (eco, on this PC), note that when power drops to 10%, this machine will Hibernate, effectively saving its state to the drive, and then power off completely.
Note that some PC's no longer support true Hibernation. On one HP machine with removable battery, I must remove the battery to prevent continuous drain to oblivion. Such machines without removable battery might require surgery (well, rewiring) to fully shut down on demand.

The available sleep states in my laptop are (Standby S0 - Hibernate - Fast Startup) also on the power plan i have critical battery action set to "Hibernate" same as yours.
i tried both (Sleep / Shutdown) when pressing shutdown button, the problem happens on both, also the problem sometimes happens if i do shutdown and leave it like 5min when the battery level is above 90% so no way it drained very low in 5min.
it really gives me the error info (mentioned) Event ID (158) "Hardware or firmware settings have changes since hibernate", but i can't figure out where this come from or how to fix it!
